# Terminate another iOS app when my app runs

Tags: ios, process

Is it possible to close another app when I open a certain app?

I need to close an app when I run my app.

I can't find any resource related to this.

Comment: Are these both your apps?

Comment: No, the app is from another developer

Comment: Nope, luckily you cannot quit other application, you cannot even quit your own - it would just annoy the user if an opened app he may want to use somehow gets force-quit by something other than his own interaction.

Comment: Ok... Thanks Josh and luk2302